# Rx .Net TestScheduler- executing immediately scheduled events

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

When I do this:

```
testScheduler.Schedule("Hello world",(scheduler, state) => Console.WriteLine(state));
testScheduler.AdvanceTo(testScheduler.Now);
```

I hit this code in `VirtualTimeSchedulerBase`:

```
public void AdvanceTo(TAbsolute time)
{
  int num = this.Comparer.Compare(time, this.Clock);
  if (num < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("time");
  if (num == 0)
    return;
```

`num == 0` is true, and I exit the method.

I can call `testScheduler.Start()` and my action will execute. But then `TestScheduler` will carry on executing everything in its queue. Whereas I want it to stop executing actions at the current time.

I can't see any other methods on TestScheduler that will get me the behaviour I want.

Is this a bug, or is it the correct behaviour but I'm missing something?

**Edit:**

I misunderstood. `TestScheduler` doesn't execute actions until *after* the date at which they are scheduled.

Scheduling an action immediately schedules it for the current value of `testScheduler.Now`. So it won't be executed until `Now + 1`.

```
  var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
  var due = new DateTime();
    testScheduler.Schedule("Hello world", due, (scheduler, s) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    return Disposable.Empty;
  });
  testScheduler.AdvanceTo(due.Ticks);
  // Nothing has happened

  testScheduler.AdvanceTo(due.Ticks+1);
  // -> "Hello world"
```

This still isn't the behaviour I would like, but there you go.

Comment: "Scheduling an action immediately schedules it for the current value of testScheduler.Now. So it won't be executed until Now + 1." - no that's wrong - it schedules for Clock + 1. It only executes when you advance because that's when you are giving the TestScheduler a time slice to process it's queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AdvanceBy(1)` to advance the scheduler by 1 tick.  The scheduler only executes events when the clock actually advances.

Different schedulers behave differently when you schedule something for immediate execution.  Some of them really do execute it immediately.  Some put it in a queue to be executed at the first available opportunity.

There's not a good way for the `TestScheduler` to behave in this situation unless the API is modified to let you tell it which way it should behave.

Comment: There's a long story behind why I didn't want to do that. I think I just have to accept the semantics of TestScheduler. I expect the Rx folks have good reasons for it looking that way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The TestScheduler actually specifically queues jobs without specified due times, or with times behind it's clock with due times as `Clock + 1`. This is why AdvanceBy(1) works... see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider how you are using the `TestScheduler`:

It *will* in general execute at the due time. For example, this code will write to the Console:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

scheduler.Schedule(
    TimeSpan.FromTicks(100),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));

scheduler.AdvanceTo(100);
```

However, `TestScheduler` will only inspect it's queue when time is moved. So if you schedule an action, you need to move time via `AdvanceBy`, `AdvanceTo` or `Start` to get it to process the queue. When it does, it will process everything up to the current time. E.g. Even this will output to the console despite scheduling "in the past":

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

scheduler.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromTicks(100).Ticks);

scheduler.Schedule(
    DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromTicks(50),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));

Console.WriteLine("No output until the scheduler is given time...");
scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
```

Idiomatic use of `TestScheduler` usually involves queuing up all your work and then running to completion via a Start() call and then checking for expected state. Use of `AdvanceBy`, `AdvanceTo` tends to be for more demanding test scenarios where you need to test some intermediate state - and even then you generally queue *everything* up first with appropriate due times and then `AdvanceBy` or `AdvanceTo` your time of interest, check state, and then progress again with `AdvanceBy`, `AdvanceTo` or `Start`.

What you don't want to do *generally* is queue work, run a bit, queue more work, run a bit - especially if you are scheduling without a due time. Then you will hit the problem you have here.

That's not to say in your specific scenario this may be unavoidable - if you need to make decisions about what to schedule after a particular time for example - but consider if you can set everything up in advance as it's probably going to result in cleaner test code that more closely follows the Arrange Act Assert pattern.

I try to Arrange by scheduling, then Act by moving time, then Assert the results.

Comment: Thanks James. Again this makes things clearer. I'm in a flow test where I say Given/When/Then/When/Then (i.e. I _do_ care about intermediate states). Even then, Start() mostly works fine. I hit problems when I have a task scheduled which in turn schedules another task in the future. Then the scheduler runs off into the future. I was also wrapping the scheduler in an implementation of my IClock interface for use as the system time. I've now decoupled my clock from the scheduler and my tests move the system time and the TestScheduler independently. More verbose but actually more correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `Start` method will execute everything scheduled.  You can schedule a `Stop` method call to pause the execution at a given point.

```
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var due = new DateTime();
        testScheduler.Schedule("Hello world", due, (scheduler, s) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });

        testScheduler.Schedule(due.Ticks + 1, (scheduler, s) => testScheduler.Stop());

        testScheduler.Schedule("Do more stuff", due.AddMinutes(1), (scheduler, s) => Console.WriteLine(s));

        testScheduler.Start();
        Assert.IsFalse(testScheduler.IsEnabled);
        Assert.AreEqual(due.Ticks + 1, testScheduler.Clock);
```