# Rx TestScheduler does not play nice with Return and Delay

Tags: unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm having trouble writing a unit test for an observable that contains a combination of `Return` and `Delay`. The problem is that the `TestScheduler` does not emit any notifications no matter what amount of time is advanced.

```cs
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var input = new Subject<bool>();

var output = scheduler.Start(() =>
    Observable.Return("feed me", scheduler)
              .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler));

scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
Assert.Equal(0, output.Messages.Count);

// Expecting an OnNext and an OnCompleted notification
scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks);
Assert.Equal(2, output.Messages.Count);
```

The weird thing is that when I add the `created`, `subscribed` and `disposed` timings to the `Start` method it does work. That's all fine and dandy, but I really need the AdvanceBy functionality. My actual test case is more complex and requires manual timing on the input of the observable.

```cs
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var source = Observable
    .Return("Winner!", scheduler)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler);
var output = scheduler.Start(() => source,
    0,
    0,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks);

Assert.Equal(2, output.Messages.Count);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used the `Start` method you're using. Never figured out how or why it should work.

This should work:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var input = new Subject<bool>();

var observable = Observable.Return("feed me")
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler);

var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();
observable.Subscribe(observer);

scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
Assert.Equal(0, observer.Messages.Count);

// Expecting an OnNext and an OnCompleted notification
scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks);
Assert.Equal(2, observer.Messages.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work nicely. It seems I'm not the only one, there is a ticket open in the Rx.NET repository regarding the `Start` overloads. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/81

Comment: See also this answer with additional details on why `AdvanceBy(1)` makes it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906872/1518546